# the value is not inserting into the textbox, it was working two days ago?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<html>
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript"

src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function insertParamIntoField(anchor, param, field) {
       var query = anchor.search.substring(1, anchor.search.length).split('&');

       for(var i = 0, kv; i < query.length; i++) {
          kv = query[i].split('=', 2);
          if (kv[0] == param) {
              field.val(kv[1]);

             return;
          }
       }
    }


$(function () {
    $("a.reply").click(function (e) {
       console.log("clicked");
       insertParamIntoField(this, "replyto", $("textarea"));
       e.preventDefault();
       return false; // prevent default action
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea></textarea>
<a class="reply" href="?replyto=you">TEST</a>
</body>
</html>
```

what im trying to is when i click the link, the replyto parameter is inserted into the textarea, in this example `"you"`it was working 2 days ago! i dnt know whats wrong

Comment: im thinking something with jquery/javascript syntax has changed or something because it was working 2 days ago! wierd

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/aPWRg/1/

Comment: i just clciked that link, and it was not working, i think its my browser maybe, but javascript is enabled!! confused

Comment: You are testing in FireFox right? Because console.log() will throw an error in other browsers and make it seem the function does not work.

Comment: Actually, there are also some cases where FireFox will not recognise console.log() either causing the same problem.

Comment: yeh im testing in firefox, so whats the solution, sorry im a newbie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit:* I falsely *assumed* you were using firebug, from comments I see you weren't and that installing it resolved your issue.  This line:

```
console.log("clicked");
```

Will blow up if firebug isn't installed and always in IE, when testing in an environment without a `console`, be sure to remove any calls to it...it'll throw a JavaScript error otherwise.

Comment: thanks for answering, i just checked your test page, and its not wokring for me, is thier something wrong with my browser, becuase javascript is enabled

Comment: @getaway - Do you have a link?  something outside the scope of the question is affecting it, since what you posted works.

Comment: @BGerrissen - IE can have issues here, not that anyone's surprised by this :)

Comment: If he's testing in IE, it's more likely that console.log() is breaking the code ;)

Comment: @getaway - As BGerrissen said, `console` isn't in IE and it'll break it too, even if the rest works...are you getting any errors in your firebug console?  If you don't have firebug, install it :)  http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: i just installed firebug, and i clicked on console and then it works, but then when i close firebug it deost work again

Comment: @getaway - Without firebug, `console.log()` doesn't work, you need to remove any `console` statements when not testing in an environment with it (this includes IE).

Comment: @getaway - `console` is the firebug console...it's not an object in JavaScript unless it's installed/running, it's not something just there by default, at least in Firefox :)

Comment: okay kool, so basically when i put my website in production i need to take off the console.log from my script!

Comment: @getaway - yes! definitely :)

Answer (score 0):

Is your internet connection working ok? You're using jQuery from google API, so what happens if you reference a local version?

Also, what happens when you click: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js?